# Trigonometry equation with double and triple A

Tags: trigonometry

Solve for $A$:
$$\sin(2A) + \sin(4A) = \cos(A) + \cos(3A),$$
but get stuck. After $$\sin(2A)(1+2\cos(2A)) = 2 \cos(A) cos (2A)$$
$$\cos(A)!=0$$ $$\sin(A)(1+2\cos(2A))=\cos(2A) $$ Can someone help?

Comment: It is not true. What happens when $A=0$?

Comment: Do you mean "solve for A"?

Comment: Yes, of course it has solution only in some points

Comment: I tried to use sin(2A) = 2 sin(A) cos(A), cos(3A)=4cos^3(A)-3 cos(A) etc, but can't find the way, when left part comes to right.

Comment: Use http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Comment: Thank you for information!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identity is the same as
$$
2\sin(3A)\cos A=2\cos (2A)\cos A.
$$
So either $\cos A=0$ or
$$
\sin(3A)=\cos(2A)=\sin(\pi/2-2A).
$$
Surely you can proceed from there.